# To detect page request and API/XHR call from backend

Tags: api, http, xmlhttprequest, http-headers

Have a single entry service which is acting like a facade/proxy service for downstream services. The service will need able to detect if the request is a "page request" or "api/xhr" request to perform error handling (302 redirection or 401).

So far have considered:

- To use Accept header and detect text/html follow the following [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation/List_of_default_Accept_values), can't tell if this is a good indicator to detect a page request
- To introduce a custom header for all "api/xhr" request
- To enforce all the "api/xhr" requests to follow a "/api" pattern (troublesome as for certain application the xhr is not a restful api)

Any good suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using Option 1

- Detect page request using Accept header with value "text/html"

As we do not use ajax for partial view

Answer (score 0):

Usually the non-standard HTTP header `X-Requested-With` is used. Just the presence of the header should be enough. It has at least one advantage over `Accept`: It cannot be set on a cross-site request, which helps preventing CSRF.

Comment: this falls under the second option which is to introduce a custom header, I have removed the "ajax" and replaced with "xhr" from the question as "ajax" are usually treated as jquery related